# Como establecer un valor dinámico a un v-select?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Tengo un select que lo lleno dinamicamente con el arreglo `vehiculos_usuarios`, el arreglo contiene objetos, el cual sus valores se muestan en el `v-select`.
Como puedo hacer para predefinir un valor en el `v-select` y al mismo tiempo se ejecute la función `@change="vehiculoSeleccionado"`, ya que dicha función solo se ejecutar al hacer un cambio en el select.

```
<template>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
      <v-select
        :items="vehiculos_usuario"
        label="Selecciona vehiculo"
        item-text="nombre"
        item-key="vehiculos_usuario"
        item-value="id"
        return-object
        @change="vehiculoSeleccionado"
       ></v-select>
    </v-flex>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
      return {
         vehiculos_usuario: [
            {
             id: "-L_UU2Ca0hEruJ8Yxwt2"
             idcategoria: "-LWPTMu1m4WYO1wzJFiv"
             nombre: "Mazda 2019 - PP223PRL"
             placa: "P223PRL"
            },
            {
             id: "-L_UYxSRD9_1rb02fp5X"
             idcategoria: "-LWPRsmK3uBYWGeixA8E"
             nombre: "Honda - Moto - CC222RRR"
             placa: "C222RRR"
            }
         ]
     }
  },
  methods:{
   vehiculoSeleccionado(val){
    console.log("Vehiculo Seleccionado");
    console.log(val);
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

De esta forma se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y basicamente quiero que al iniciar en la vista el select contega un valor predefinido, pero siempre y cuando sean del arreglo `vehiculos_usuarios`
y se vea de esta forma, al mismo tiempo ejecutando la funcion `vehiculoSeleccionado`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No he podido comprobarlo, pero creo que esto puede hacer lo que necesitas:

```
<template>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
      <v-select
        :items="vehiculos_usuario"
        label="Selecciona vehiculo"
        item-text="nombre"
        item-key="vehiculos_usuario"
        item-value="id"
        v-model="vehiculos_usuario[0]"
        return-object
        @change="vehiculoSeleccionado"
       ></v-select>
    </v-flex>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
      return {
         vehiculos_usuario: [
            {
             id: "-L_UU2Ca0hEruJ8Yxwt2"
             idcategoria: "-LWPTMu1m4WYO1wzJFiv"
             nombre: "Mazda 2019 - PP223PRL"
             placa: "P223PRL"
            },
            {
             id: "-L_UYxSRD9_1rb02fp5X"
             idcategoria: "-LWPRsmK3uBYWGeixA8E"
             nombre: "Honda - Moto - CC222RRR"
             placa: "C222RRR"
            }
         ]
     }
  },
  methods:{
   vehiculoSeleccionado(val){
    console.log("Vehiculo Seleccionado");
    console.log(val);
   }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.vehiculoSeleccionado(this.vehiculos_usuario[0].id);
  }
}
</script>
```

Le asignamos un valor inicial al select con `v-model` y cuando el componente esté montado (quiere decir que también está montado los componentes hijos), llamamos a la función.

Comment: Igual yo aclararia que de hacerlo de esta forma, el valor es cualquier cosa menos dinamico, ya que siempre es el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr v-for="index in cantidadProc" :key="index"  v-bind:id="index"> 
<td scope="row">{{index}}</td>
<td> <input :id="'date_' + index" type="date" :min="myDate" class="form-control" required></td>
<td>
    <v-select 
        :clearable="true"
        label="name" 
        v-model="professional[index]" 
        :options="professional_options" 
        @search="fetchOptions" 
        @input="selectedOption(index,professional[index])" >
    </v-select>
</tr>
```

```
data: {
professional: [],
professional_options: [],
}
```

```
selectedOption: function(index, professional){
            console.log("value : " + index);
            console.log(professional.id);
            Planeacion.professional[index] = professional;
            
        },
```

**Esto lo hice para agregar varios v-select dentro de una tabla**